# Disable or stop blocking content in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

Is it possible to stop or disable a content blocker from an app without using the safari section in the settings app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**

You can use NSFileManager to open the `blockerList.json` file and modify it's content. Just remove the blocks in the file when you want your blocker to be disabled and add it back when you want to enable it.

You should also keep a backup of your blockers in a second file just in case.

I haven't tried this but I figure it should be possible.

Comment: Thank you but that is not what I mean. I want to disable blocking content from the content blocker app itself.

Comment: Which one are you using?

Comment: I am using my own blocker.

Comment: Then you should refine your question.

Comment: I think it should be clear. Any suggestions?

Comment: Does your app even have UI or is it just a swift extension to safari? You didn't give ANY information on your issue.

Comment: It’s not in swift, it’s in objective-c. My only question was - is it POSSIBLE. So what information do you need?

Comment: And yes, it has a UI.

Comment: Of course it's possible if your app has UI. I suppose you have a .json file with your blocks in it. You could change the contents of that file depending if you want to block content or not. (NSFileManager is a good start)

Comment: thank you. That is all I wanted 

Comment: I edited my answer for you. You're welcome